# @Input in Angular2 not working

Tags: angular, angular2-template

I've already searched for an answer for this, but really do not know why the heck this is not working...see my components source code:

ts file:

```
import { Component, Input } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
    moduleId: module.id,
    selector: 'alerta',
    templateUrl: 'alerta.component.html',

})

export class AlertaComponent {

    // Os atributos abaixo são inputs, serão alimentados pelo componente "pai"

    @Input() messageStatus: string;

}
```

Here, my template file:

```
<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<!-- jQuery library -->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<!-- Latest compiled JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<div class="alert alert-warning alert-dismissable" >
    <a href="#" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="close">×</a>{{ messageStatus }}
</div>
```

And here, how i am putting in my another component:

```
 <alerta messageStatus="teste"></alerta>
```

I don´t see a single reason to no be working...the input feature is not desplaying on the screen its content. Any ideia?

Comment: What does "other component" mean? What is `teste`?

Comment: `<script>` tags in component templates are not supported. They are just removed.

Comment: "teste" its just a simple string, it means "test. The other component has a extense code, but in a nutshell, the template of the other component has my "<alerta" component and displays it nicely, but the contente of the @Input it is not being displayed.

Comment: Then it should work as it is.

Answer (score 0):

```
<alerta [messageStatus]="teste"></alerta>
```

or if it's a string value this will work as well

```
<alerta messageStatus="{{teste}}"></alerta>
```

Without `[]` and `{{}}` there is no Angular binding happening. Instead `teste` is passed as a literal string.

Comment: Tried both ways, still not working, nothing is being displayed:

Comment: Hard to tell. There is nothing magical with binding. With the right syntax, it usually just works. Hard to tell why it's not working in your case.

Comment: yeah, i know...i just cant believe why does not work, its so simple to do it. I'll try to rebuild my component from scratch.

Answer (score 0):

any logs from console? maybe you didn't add component to declarations in @ngModule?

Answer (score 0):

send your input in parent template

```html
<alerta [messageStatus]="teste"></alerta>

secound in child view check the input with ngIf

<div *ngIf="messageStatus" class="alert alert-warning alert-dismissable">

    <a href="#" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="close">×</a>{{ messageStatus }}
  </div>
```